# Dynamic height viewpager for images (onMeasure() not working)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a custom ViewPager inside of an RecyclerView. I made `wrap_content` height of ViewPager and put `onMeasure()` function inside of CustomViewPager. But when I scroll down and up the `RecyclerView`, sometimes ViewPager is disappear. I look many SO answers but `onMeasure()` function not working every time for me. Method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); //Deneme

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    if (height != 0) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

`ViewPager` XML:

```
<com.monster.vpagerapp.Utils.ViewPagerFixedPost
            android:id="@+id/postsViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also I use this in constructor of RecylerView:

```
setHasStableIds(true);
```

And use this in MainFragment

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(1, 0); //for unnecessary refresh
```

Comment: You have a viewpager *inside* a recycler view? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Speed because I want to make a Feed Page like Instagram to load posts. I use Viewpager because I load multiple images from server. So I have to use ViewPager.

Comment: So you want each item of the recyclerview to be the height of the screen, and then the contents of the item (so the viewpagers) to fill that height?

Comment: @Speed for example let's say some images height is 200dp and some images height is 500dp. I want whenever image height is 500dp, so my viewpager height must be 500dp too. Or if my images height is 200dp so my viewpager height must be 200dp

Comment: So this is basically wrap_content logic you know. But when I set height to wrap_content sometimes my viewpager images may be dissepear.